# Termination of HTML form by javascript

Tags: javascript

I have made a form in which I am asking "Do you make use of this service?".I don't want the remaining questions to appear If the user clicks on the radio button "no". How can I make use of javascript to do this?

Comment: Please post the code you have in your question, showing us what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Please do mark my post as an answer if you found it helpful and it solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Put the rest of your form in a div and then include this js.  I'd advise putting it in script tags at the end of the document, otherwise you'll have to wrap it all in `window.onload{}`.

Also, this will work for checkboxes which makes more sense to me for a yes/no question.  I've added a comment for the slight edit you'll need to make it work for radio buttons.

```
// give the radio button an easy name
var r_b = document.getElementById("radio-button's-id-here");
// and give the div a nice selector
var serv = document.getElementById("the-div's-id");
// listen to when it is clicked
r_b.addEventListener("click",checked,false);
// optional: you originally specified radio buttons which means you'll need to add an event listener for the no option
// lastly include a function to handle everything
function checked (){
    // check its status
    if (r_b.checked){
        // hide the form
        serv.style.display = "none";
    }else{
        serv.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm on my phone, so this is untested and may have typos.

Edit: you don't need to use cookies unless the form is on another page or if you expect users to see this exact page many times without being prompted

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/58urhgen/

```
<form>
    Do you make use of this service?
    <input type="radio" name="my-radio" value="Yes" onclick="document.getElementById('service-used').style.display='block';document.getElementById('service-not-used').style.display='none';" /> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="my-radio" value="No" onclick="document.getElementById('service-used').style.display='none';document.getElementById('service-not-used').style.display='block';" /> No
    <div id="service-used" style="display:none;">
        <p>You use the service!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="service-not-used" style="display:none;">
        <p>Doesn't use the service!</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

I've simply used event handlers of the radio buttons to show/hide the respected portions of the form depending on the user's choice. I think this is what you're trying to achieve.

PS: This is not the best practice but this is just to show you how it can be achieved. You can use functions to make your code tidy.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Cookie to store the form status. [`http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: This doesn't seem very relevant to the question.